# What is the meaning of the different color nodes of this bezier curve?

Tags: interface, bezier-curves

Why are the above ones red and the bottom ones orange? Nothing is selected and this Bézier curve is the result of joining one Bézier curve to this one, so chances are something I joined to this was different, but how?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the handle type with the <kbd>V</kbd> key. The yellow handles are *Automatic*, it allows to smooth the curve, pink handles are *Aligned*, which are classical handles. *Vector* and *Free* allow to manipulate each handle independently, *Vector* for sharp angle, *Free* for round angle.

Comment: three years using Blender and only now learned the difference :))

Comment: @Jachym Michal, I also always need to relearn every time  ;)

Answer (score 5):

The colors correspond to the type of the handles for each control point. You can set the handle type via the *Control Points > Set Handle Type* menu (shortcut:  <kbd>V</kbd>).

You can also see and change these colors in *Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport* panel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The colours correspond to the type of handle being used at each of the points.

By the looks of it, you've got a mixture of Aligned and Automatic handles, according to this diagram from the Blender docs site: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/structure.html#id2

The different handle types affect how your curve behaves and how the line travels through each point. You can open a menu to choose a handle type by selecting one or more handles and pressing `V`.